# flex undefined definition

Tags: gnu, bison, flex-lexer

I'm very new to flex and I can't figure out why my definitions are invalid. I'm sure I'm making some simple mistake. Here's a sample of my code, with the missing parts being similar definitions and rules. Any insight as to why it won't compile?

```
%{
include <math.h>
%}

DIGIT [0-9]
NUM {DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}+

%%
{NUM}+   {printf("%f ", atof(yytext());}
%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the following:

```
#include <math.h>
...
printf("%f ", atof(yytext));
```

The compiler error messages are a bit misleading..